# How to access a try-with-resource variable outside the block?

Tags: java

Why can't I assign a `try-with-resource variable` outside of the try block?

The following statement is invalid:

```
Connection con = null;
try (con = DatabaseService.getConnection()) { //this is invalid. why?
     con.execute(...);
} catch (Exception e) {
    con.rollback();
}
```

How can I get access to the `con` variable inside the `catch` block?

Comment: You are supposed to declare it within the round parenthesis, so that the resource can be automatically closed in the implicit `finally` statement.

Comment: Do you really need access to `con` to do `rollback` only? Probably you could encapsulate your payload into `Function` and hide `try...cath` from the client and your payload function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd design it like this:

```
try (Connection con = DatabaseService.getConnection()) {
    try {
        con.execute(...);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        con.rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: **P.S.** *IntelliJ IDEA* inspections provide warning (by default) for `try... catch` inside another `try...catch`

Comment: Ok so I'd have to introduce a nested try-catch block if I got you right. I hoped I could prevent this...

Comment: @oleg.cherednik it happens, it's a warning that maybe something is wrong, but for this case, it isn't.

Answer (score 11):

This is only with Java version 8. It has improved Since Java 9.

With Java 9 the Try-With-Resources has been improved by introducing a new syntax:

```
public void loadDataFromDB() throws SQLException {
    Connection dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "user", "password");
    try (dbCon; ResultSet rs = dbCon.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from emp")) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("In method loadDataFromDB()" + rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured while reading data from DB " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The same when compiled with Java 8 or lesser version will result in a compilation error.

In Java 9 you can use the variables in the scope of try and catch blocks.

Answer (score 4):

Since try-with-resources calls `close()` on a AutoCloseable class, you could go back to manually closing the connection:

```
Connection con = DatabaseService.getConnection();
try {
    con.execute(...);
} catch (Exception e) {
    con.rollback();
} finally {
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: `AutoCloseable` would be suitable than `Closeable`.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, since Java 9 you can use try-with-resources with final or effective final variables. So you can initialize the variable outside the try block, and just indicate that you want to use it in the try-with-resources block. This way the variable is available in the scope of the catch block.

```java
Connection con = DatabaseService.getConnection();
try (con) {
     con.execute(...);
} catch (Exception e) {
    con.rollback();
}
```

Note: Even though the variable will be available in the catch method, the call to the `close()` method will happen before it enters the catch or finally blocks. So in this case it won't be useful to call a `rollback()` in a transaction, but it is to gather additional information from the object state.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on answer from *@Luiggi Mendoza*:

```
public void doWithConnection() throws SQLException {
    try (Connection con = DatabaseService.getConnection()) {
        execute(con);
    }
}

private void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    try {
        // TODO do smth. here
    } catch(Exception e) {
        con.rollback();
    }
}
```